# How to call ID through local Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables

if am having html

```
<TableView id=img1></TableView>
<TableView id=img2></TableView>
```

normally

```
  $.img1.backgroundImage = "/Picture1.jpeg"
```

but I want to know how to store the `id` in local variable and call the same function, in place of `img1` I have to use local variable. is any possibility of this.

Comment: yeah , shouldn't it be $('#img1').backgroundImage ?

Comment: var a = "#img1";
$(a).css("backgrround-image", your_image);

Comment: @God: Sorry but, I cant understand, why are you setting an image background for an image element.

Comment: @undefined: yes, but at least not in HTML.

Comment: Thank You all including those gave minus. next time i will not make mistake. thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better save the object instead of id as you would need to get element by id again and again.

```
var img1Obj1 = $('#img1');  //jQuery object
var img1Obj2 = $('#img1')[0]; // DOM javascript object
```

Comment: He wants to use the id not the entire element.

Comment: It will be better and helpful if people also give reasons for down votes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes Sure but need to adjust the code accordingly to set the background image

```
var img1 = $("#img1")
img1.css("background-image","/Picture1.jpeg");
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally `$.img1.backgroundImage = "/Picture1.jpeg"` would be nonsense since jQuery doesn't populate itself with properties referencing all elements with ids on a page.

Converting that to use a variable instead of an identifier (let's say `var foo = 'img1';` for the benefit of all the following examples) would be

```
$[foo].backgroundImage = "/Picture1.jpeg";
```

(That's equivalent to the original code, but since I wouldn't expect the original to work, this won't either).

To actually set the `backgroundImage` property in JS you would:

```
document.getElementById(foo).style.backgroundImage = "url(/Picture1.jpeg)";
```

or if you are being a jQuery junkie:

```
jQuery('#' + foo).css('background-image', 'url(/Picture1.jpeg)');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var images = $("#img1");
```

or also you can use

```
var images_obj=form_name.element_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var yourVar= $("#img1").attr("id");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to change the background image css property of an element selected by id, who is in a local variable?

```
var yourid = "img1";
$('#' + yourid ).css('background-image', '/Picture1.jpeg');
```